# How to solve this task with lists?

Tags: python

Making a list from mainlist and from subslists

Comment: Solve it without list comprehensions first, then figure out how (if at all) list comprehensions can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend breaking up the problems into two steps:

1. Generate the list of pyramid bricks (without the empty spaces)
2. Add in the empty spaces (as needed) to each element of that list

As for Step 1, you can easily accomplish it with this function:

```
def pyramid(base, char):
    result = [[char] * i for i in range(1, base+1, 2)]
    return result
```

Do you see what it's doing?  It's looping through a range of odd numbers, and for each number, it is constructing a list of chars.  Each constructed list will be an element of the returned result list.

So if you call `pyramid(5, 'A')`, you'll get:

```
[['A'], ['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']]
```

This solution does not account for the empty spaces, however.  To handle those empty spaces, you could either:

1. Run the `result` through a second list comprehension, or:
2. Edit the first (and only) list comprehension to include the proper number of spaces at the beginning and end of each sub-list.

I'll let you decide how to implement this for yourself.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As chepner said, try write your own code without list comprehension and then modify your own code.

```
def pyramid(base, char):
  return [ ['']*num_empty + [char]*num_char + ['']*num_empty for num_empty, num_char in enumerate(list(range(base, 0, -2)))][::-1]
```